# How can I download ListView HTML images asynchronously?

Tags: android, html, listview, android-listview, android-asynctask

As a prototype, I'm trying to modify the [android-imagedownloader demo](http://code.google.com/p/android-imagedownloader/) from the [Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html) to work with HTML image tags rather than hard-coded `ImageViews`.  I've modified it by replacing `ImageAdapter.getView()` with the following:

```
public View getView(final int position, View view, final ViewGroup parent) {
   TextView textView = (TextView) view;
    if (textView == null) {
       textView = new TextView(parent.getContext());
       textView.setPadding(6, 6, 6, 6);
    }
    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<img src=\"" + URLS[position] + "\"/>", 
       new ImageGetter() {
       @Override public Drawable getDrawable(final String source) {
          ImageView imageView = new ImageView(parent.getContext());
          imageDownloader.download(source, imageView);
          return imageView.getDrawable();
       }
    }, null));

    return textView;
}
```

None of the images are appearing in the ListView though and no errors are reported in Logcat.  Do `TextViews` unlike `ImageViews` need to be refreshed somehow once the images are downloaded?

The original `getView()` was:

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (view == null) {
        view = new ImageView(parent.getContext());
        view.setPadding(6, 6, 6, 6);
    }

    imageDownloader.download(URLS[position], (ImageView) view);

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to abandon my original idea of using HTML `TextView` to render my images since I don't think it will be a problem to limit the layout to a single image per `TextView`.  For those who still really want to do this, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3767016/403455) should guide you to the right solution.  You'd have to pass the `TextView` to the `BitmapDownloaderTask` and in `onPostExecute` call `setText` again but with the newly downloaded or "decached" image.

It might also be necessary to force an update of the row in the `ListView` per [Romain Guy's guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9987714/403455).